# How to use bootstrap admin template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I see lot of websites proposing website admin template based on bootstrap (i.e wrapbootstrap.com).
I was wondering how to use this type of templates? 
Do I need to develop the logic by myself ? 
thanks for helping.

Comment: Bootstrap is a CSS framework, you would still need to write your admin pages yourself.

Comment: I know what is bootstrap :) I was wondering how to take benefit to the admin template and how people use the admin template.

Comment: It depends upon the template. Some have implemented logic, and others are strictly UI. I wouldn't recommend using WrapBootstrap if you're looking for support/help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you do need to develop the logic yourself. You use the template by applying it to the logic you develop.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap admin templates are basically a collection of web pages that are created using the front-end framework, Bootstrap. They are created with the intention of helping you kick-start your Bootstrap projects. Keep in mind, they can only help you create the front-end of your projects quickly and easily. They are not a fully-functional admin panel. You still need to use backend languages like PHP to make the template a fully-functional application. You can read this article to know [all about Bootstrap admin templates](https://www.bootstrapdash.com/things-to-know-bootstrap-admin-templates/) . Also, the article [Bootstrap 4 Application with php](https://hackernoon.com/bootstrap-4-application-with-php-3d726458cbd5) details about how to make a Bootstrap admin template into a functional back-end application .